# require doesn't load asdf system in ~/common-lisp/ subdirectories

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

(require :your-system) doesn't load system but system exist in asdf standard directory ~/common-lisp/.

```
CL-USER> (require :your-system)
Don't know how to REQUIRE YOUR-SYSTEM.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:EXTENSION-FAILURE]
```

~/common-lisp/log-simple/YOUR-SYSTEM.asdf:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage log-simple-asd
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :log-simple-asd)

(defsystem log-simple
 ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you `(require "asdf")` first?
If you didn't, do.
And if you did, it's better to explicitly call `(asdf:load-system ...)` than have it be implictly called by `(require ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

When asdf process directory that contains files with different codebase(for example in :utf-8) than asdf skip it without show any error or warning. You can set default format in ~/.sbclrc file, for example:

```
(setf sb-alien::*default-c-string-external-format* :utf-8)
```